# SQL query within another query

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing customers and another containing all orders.

I want to display a list of customers and along side show the total value of their orders.

Obviously I could loop through the customers and then using PHP run another query to get each customer's revenue. I don't think this is efficient.

I am looking to achieve something like this:

```
SELECT username, [SELCT sum(revenue) from orders where userID=userID] from customers
```

And for this to show output:

```
bob      10000
jeff     25000
alan     500
```

Comment: you can always compare the performance between join and correlated subqueries.

Comment: The subselect used there is likely to perform slowly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're close...

```
 SELECT username, (SELECT sum(revenue) from orders where userID=c.userID) rev 
 from customers c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.username, SUM(b.revenue) totalRevenue
FROM    customers a
        LEFT JOIN Orders b
            ON a.userID = b.UserID
GROUP   BY a.username
```

This will list all customers with or without `Orders`.

To further learn more about join, please visit the article below,

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables and the group them by the order name

```
SELECT o.username, 
       sum(revenue) as sum_revenue
from orders  o
left outer join customers c on c.userid = o.userid
group by o.username
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a subselect with that. Try something like this:-

```
SELECT customers.userID, customers.username, SUM(revenue)
FROM customers INNER JOIN orders ON customers.userID = orders.userID
GROUP BY customers.userID, customers.username
```